# How do I fill a Delphi set?

Tags: delphi, set

If I have a type defined as a **set of** an enumerated type, it's easy to create an empty set with [], but how do I create a *full* set?

EDIT:  Yeah, the obvious solution is to use a for loop.  That's also a really bad solution if there's another way. Does anyone know of a way that'll work in constant time?

Comment: You know it's a bitset, so use that knowledge and fill it with all-1s. There is no language primitive for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Low() and High() are "compiler magic" functions that can be evaluated at compile time.
This allows their use in constant declarations like the following:

```
var
  MySet : TBorderIcons;
  MySet2 : TBorderIcons;
const
  AllIcons : TBorderIcons = [Low(TBorderIcon)..High(TBorderIcon)];
begin
  MySet := [Low(TBorderIcon)..High(TBorderIcon)];
  MySet2 := AllIcons;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

Per Barry's suggestion:

```
FillChar(VarSet, SizeOf(VarSet), $FF);
```